# Connect a Django user to a Discord server and assign a role

Tags: django, api, authentication, discord

I see a lot of pip package to manage bots or messages in Discord via Django, however, I'm just looking for a simple way to connect a client of my Django website to my discord server.

I need to be able to add or remove them from the discord, assign them a role.

Can you point me to a maintained package that would help me do this?